# Google Cloud Endpoint - Error when project runs backend configuration

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I was following the Hello Endpoints tutorial here:(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints)

After I imported the module, and ran the "backend"configuration, I receive this message in the logcat. I went to the appspot link associated with my project and it appears to be working properly, but this message kind of bothers me. How can I fix the problem?

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\override\appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --address=localhost --port=8080 C:\Apps\AppEngineTest\backend\build\exploded-app
Sep 06, 2015 8:16:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Apps\AppEngineTest\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Sep 06, 2015 8:16:41 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Apps\AppEngineTest\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF/web.xml
Sep 06, 2015 8:16:41 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Apps\AppEngineTest\backend\build\exploded-app\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'

************************************************
Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use: bind
Try overriding --address and/or --port.

Process finished with exit code 2


"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\override\appengine-dev-jdk-overrides.jar -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Users\Mike\.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --address=localhost --port=8080 C:\Apps\AppEngineTest\backend\build\exploded-app
********************************************************
The API version in this SDK is no longer supported on the server!
-----------

    Latest SDK:
    Release: 1.9.26
    Timestamp: Tue Jul 28 14:00:50 CDT 2015
    API versions: [1]

    -----------
    Your SDK:
    Release: 1.9.18
    Timestamp: Thu Feb 12 13:30:16 CST 2015
    API versions: [1.0]
```

I downloaded the latest version of app engine sdk from the link it provided, but i'm not quite sure what to do with that folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem:

my localhost:8080 port was in use by another app I had previously ran. Kill the process that was taking up that spot, and it works.

1. open command prompt
2. type:   netstat -aon | findstr "8080"
3. noted the PID
4. opened up task manager
5. view > select columns > add the column for PID
6. search through your processes and find the one that cooreseponds with the PID. In my case it was "java.exe"
7. kill the task and you're good!